Coloring citations on Beamer slides
I am writing a slide deck in Beamer. I have to cite papers and I want to cite them in a different color. My problem is when I cite some of the papers using \citep*{}, the closing brackets of citation are colored in black but when I cite papers using \citet*{}, the opening arm of citation bracket is colored while the closing arm of bracket is not. This is what I mean:

I looked around and it seems there are some related questions and aswers online but none of them worked for me. I will appreciate advice on how to color both arms of citation bracket. I include my MWE. My main .tex file looks like:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{natbib}
\hypersetup{
colorlinks,
citecolor=red
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Extensive evidence \citep*{ongena2000determines,kosekova2023firm} 
    \item Papers \citet*{gerali2010credit}, \citet*{jermann2012macroeconomic}
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{References}
\bibliographystyle{ecta}
\bibliography{ref}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

My .bib file looks like:
@article{ongena2000determines,
title={What determines the number of bank relationships? Cross-country evidence},
author={Ongena, Steven and Smith, David C},
journal={Journal of Financial intermediation},
volume={9},
number={1},
pages={26--56},
year={2000},
publisher={Elsevier},
note = {\url{https://doi.org/10.1006/jfin.1999.0273}}
}
@article{kosekova2023firm,
title={Firm-bank relationships: a cross-country comparison},
author={Kosekova, Kamelia and Maddaloni, Angela and Papoutsi, Melina and Schivardi, Fabiano},
year={2023},
publisher={ECB Working Paper},
journal={ECB Working Paper},
note={\url{https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecb.wp2826~cbbb571758.en.pdf}}
}
@article{gerali2010credit,
title={Credit and Banking in a DSGE Model of the Euro Area},
author={Gerali, Andrea and Neri, Stefano and Sessa, Luca and Signoretti, Federico M},
journal={Journal of money, Credit and Banking},
volume={42},
pages={107--141},
year={2010},
publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
@article{jermann2012macroeconomic,
title={Macroeconomic effects of financial shocks},
author={Jermann, Urban and Quadrini, Vincenzo},
journal={American Economic Review},
volume={102},
number={1},
pages={238--271},
year={2012},
publisher={American Economic Association}
}

